# How can I add all the music from my pc to the windows 8 music app?

Tags: windows-8, music

The problem is it only adds certain albums I already added all my music folders to the music libraries sorry for my english can someone help me?
ps:there is no update available in the store.

Comment: Will you please more clear what have you tried yet to add all music to your Windows8 music app, also where is your all music files have stored on disk(e.g. in which volume of disk)?

Comment: sorry i dont understand your first question but the second my music is stored in different partitions.

Comment: I mean in my first line that What method did you tried to add the music to windows8 music app. If you understand English then use **Google Translate" to translate it in your language to understand clearly.

Comment: I tried adding all my music folders to my music library in libraries using windows explorer thanks for answer

Comment: Check out this [Articel](http://www.guidingtech.com/14089/add-files-windows-8-music-video-apps-permanently/) and this [MS article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/play-music#1TC=t1) for adding music.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste all the music into your Music Library. Or if you don't wanna copy/paste it, include it in the library. Open your music library. In the Library Tools which appears in the Title Bar, click Manage Library button. Click "Add" in the dialog box and locate the folder you wanna add to your music app and library. 
The music app detects all the music present in your music library, including any locations you add by the above method.